# MySQL - copy records over to another table and remove existing one

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm trying to process the following in one sql statement - I want to copy the number of records to the archive table and straight away remove the existing ones from the main table.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO `table_archive` 
SELECT * FROM `table_main`
WHERE `id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
REMOVE FROM `table_main` WHERE `id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

It's basically like cutting and pasting records from one table to another.

Obviously the above statement is just what I want to achieve - any idea if it's achievable at all and what sql statement would it be?

Comment: It is not possible to do with just one query.

Comment: yeah - that's what I thought - but can I at least insert records with IN range using one statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned you need to use several DML commands:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `table_archive`  SELECT * FROM `table_main` WHERE `id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4); 
DELETE`table_main` WHERE `id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4); 
COMMIT;
```

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: Thanks Kevin - I think this answers my question.

Comment: What if i have other tables Referenced by foreign key` on `Update and delete Cascade` to the table `table_main`. How to archive those tables data ? @Kevin

Comment: deal with them as you would normally... remove the referential records in the relevant tables until you can remove the main table data.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this in a single query. You can, however, try to do it within a transaction, so that it'll be TREATED as a single query. Either everything succeeds, or not happens at all.

This presumes that your tables are of InnoDB type. MyISAM does not support transactions.

Comment: yeah - they are MyISAM as there are no relations between them so no need for InnoDB

Comment: Then you'll have to do it as two separate queries, and hope that nothing breaks in between. InnoDB isn't just for foreign keys. It works perfectly fine without FKs. Being able to use transactions is a MAJOR bonus to switching - the only thing you "lose" is fulltext indexes.

Comment: Thanks Marc - isn't InnoDB also a bit slower than MyISAM? Also I haven't used Transactions before - are they automatically executed whenever I interact with the table or do I need to trigger them using some specific statement? And also - when I export database structure - are they also exported or do I need to define them again after the import of the sql with the structure?

Comment: InnoDB has a little bit more overhead than myisam, and *IS* slower on things like count(*), but is faster for other things because it supports row-level locking (myisam only has table-level locks). By default it runs in auto-commit mode - each query automatically commits. You have to explicitly start a transaction, or run with auto-commit off. if you do a mysqldump, it'll export the entire database (structure + data) as plaintext in SQL command syntax. It basically makes a file that can recreate the entire DB as it was at the moment the dump occured.

Comment: Sorry Mark - I've mixed the TRANSACTION with a ROUTINE - so does TRANSACTION work like a wrapper for a number of statements to be executed at the same time - say INSERT INTO SELECT; DELETE and then COMMIT at the end of transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Not at all possible. Do a separate DELETE and wrap the entire thing in a transaction (if you are using a language that supports transactions, as opposed to the MYSQL console which I'm not sure supports transactions).